# All possible product combinations with k columns and n rows for each

Tags: c++, vba, excel, combinations

I have a few columns of data with the same number of rows that I would like to combine and get all of the possible product combinations between them.
For example, if a have 4 columns A,B,C, D of n rows, I'd like to have 11 more columns with the following columns products:

```
A*B 
A*C
A*D
B*C
B*D
C*D
A*B*C
A*B*D
A*C*D
B*C*D
A*B*C*D
```

I wrote a VBA and a C++ program to get all the 2x2 product combinations but I'm stuck there.

Comment: Why do you talk about row ?

Comment: All columns should have the same number of rows here

Comment: What did you write? Where are you stuck?

Comment: what do you mean with "column product" ? elementwise multiplication?

Comment: what do you mean with "all the 2x2 product combinations"? is AD a 2x2 product combination?

Comment: Exactly ,by "column product" I mean elementwise multiplication
I have a data matrix **G** with **nbfactors** columns 
Here is a vba code for all the 2*2 element wise multiplication .
The first nbfactors columns of **Gtest** contains the elements of **G** 

`` col = nb_factors
    For i = 1 To nbfactors - 1
        For j = i + 1 To nbfactors
        col = col + 1
            For k = 1 To n
            Gtest(k, col) = G(k, i) * G(k, j)
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i

Comment: Sorry for the comments. I'm new in stackoverflow, I'll check how to post a code and make it clear

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have less than 32 initial columns, you may do:

```
void print_new_combinations(const std::vector<std::string>& v)
{
    assert(v.size() < 32);// else you have to use bigger type.

    for (std::uint32_t i = 0; i < (1 << v.size()); ++i) {
        if ((i & (i - 1)) != 0) { // filter empty set or unique set
            print_combination(v, i);
        }
    }
}

void print_combination(const std::vector<std::string>& v, std::uint32_t mask)
{
    for (std::uint32_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) {
        if ((mask & (1 << i)) != 0) {
            std::cout << " " << v[i];
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/KqOykG)